# TSQL Muliple Recordsets

Tags: t-sql

I am using a cursor to loop through a recordset and insert the values into another table however the result when I run the code gives me 3 different recordsets as its printing the select into a recordset each time it loops. I want the code to loop through and insert but the result to only show the last recordset containing the @OUT_STATUS.

```
    DECLARE loop_Cursor CURSOR FOR  
((SELECT Picknote, noparts, nolines from dbo.pickdet where batchid =     @helpingwith )) 
OPEN loop_Cursor;  
FETCH NEXT FROM loop_Cursor;  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
  BEGIN  
 INSERT into dbo.Pickdet (batchid,nolines,noparts,fullpart) VALUES     (@new_identity, @nolines, @noparts, 'Helper')
  FETCH NEXT FROM loop_Cursor;  
   END;  
CLOSE loop_Cursor;  
DEALLOCATE loop_Cursor;  

SELECT  @OUT_STATUS = 'SUCCESS',@OUT_STATUS_DESCRIPTION = 'Packing Batch Created' 


SELECT  @OUT_STATUS as out_status,@OUT_STATUS_DESCRIPTION as out_status_description,  @new_identity AS new_identity, @pickingnow AS old_id
```

Comment: I think your syntax should be `FETCH NEXT FROM YourCursor INTO @Param1, @Param2 .....`. And you could use `INSERT INTO Yourtable(Col1,...) SELECT Col1... ` without cursor

Comment: You're selecting from dbo.pickdet and inserting into dbo.Pickdet - this is the same table, Yes?
Also, you don't need a loop here.

Comment: You might be better of restating what you want to achieve, without referencing you current code.